# Subtracting file extention from file name

Tags: php

I use PHP to get a random .ogg file then play it to the user. I would like to display the filename to the user, but the (.ogg) extension is shown too.

```
<?php
$sounds = array("Blah - Artist.ogg", "Blah1 - Artist2.ogg");
$rand_sound = array_rand($sounds);
?>
```

This is the song name output:

```
<p class="text"> Now playing: <?php echo $sounds[$rand_sound]; ?> </p>
```

How can I just display the file name? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or use some regex

Comment: Have you tried looking through the list of [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)? Have you found anything interesting? Or maybe you googled for file name and stripping and found [this](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this too I believe:

```
pathinfo($sounds[$rand_sound],PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Comment: PHP < 5.2.0 solution: `list(, $basename, $extension) = pathinfo($sounds[$rand_sound]); $filename = basename($basename, ".$extension");`

Comment: @PauloFreitas pathinfo is a costly operation..take a look at my solutions.

Comment: @redreggae Costly? How much microseconds? You're assuming he'll have only .ogg files and IMHO over optimizing and complicating a trivial task. :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<?php echo basename($sounds[$rand_sound], '.ogg'); ?>
```

Might be faster:

```
<?php echo substr($sounds[$rand_sound], 0, -4); ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php echo str_replace('.ogg', '', $sounds[$rand_sound]); ?>
```

Or for every extension:

```
<?php echo substr($sounds[$rand_sound], 0, strrpos($sounds[$rand_sound], '.')); ?>
```

Similar but works also if file has no extension:

```
<?php echo substr($sounds[$rand_sound], 0, strrpos($sounds[$rand_sound], '.') ? : strlen($sounds[$rand_sound])); ?>
```

Perhaps the best solution (works in all cases):

```
<?php echo str_replace(strrchr($sounds[$rand_sound], '.'), '', $sounds[$rand_sound]); ?>
```

EDIT:

The above functions were a test because it is fun to find new ways of doing things. But I recommend to use PHP's native functions `pathinfo` or `basename`. So if you know the extension take the first solution with `basename`, else take one of the following approaches.

PHP >= 5.2

```
<?php echo pathinfo($sounds[$rand_sound], PATHINFO_FILENAME); ?>
```

PHP < 5.2

```
<?php
echo basename(
    $sounds[$rand_sound],
    '.'.pathinfo($sounds[$rand_sound], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
);
?>
```

Comment: well all of your solutions are faster than regular expression but neither simpler nor more flexible. For example what happens when he has ogg file without extension? Your #2 solution will fail. And what happens when he has file named like aaa.bbb.ogg? Your solution #4 fails. And what happens when he has mp3 file? He has to rewrite this code. If this is just several filenames per request no harm will be done by using regex.

Comment: @hynner aaa.bbb.ogg will not fail with solution #4..only filename without extension will fail..

Comment: @redreagge sorry I didn´t notice that additional r in strrpos, so that´s probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/\.[^\.]*$/", "", $sounds[$rand_sound]); ?>
```

Comment: Regular expressions where `explode` + `implode` + `sub_array` will suffice?

Comment: `explode` + `implode` where `pathinfo` or `basename` will suffice? :)